# Creating multiple HTML table from multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to create multiple HTML tables from multidimensional array. I already built an array but I don't have any idea on how to translate that array into more than one HTML tables.

I want to separate the tables based on the time and class name that opens in the current day.

To make things clear, here is my code:

```php
$title    = [];
$table_rows  = [];

// build table arrays
foreach ($schedule AS $row)
{
    $title[]    = $row->time.' - '.$row->class_name;
    $table_rows[$row->time][$row->class_name][] = ['student_id' => $row->student_id, 'mentor_code' => $row->mentor_code, 'student_name' => $row->student_name];
}

// $title array (using array_unique($title) to removes duplicate values
Array
(
    [0] => 07:30-08:30 - E-1
    [1] => 08:30-09:30 - E-1
    [2] => 10:00-11:00 - E-1
    [3] => 11:00-12:00 - E-1
    [12] => 07:30-08:30 - E-2
    [13] => 08:30-09:30 - E-2
)

// $table_rows array
Array
(
    [07:30-08:30] => Array
        (
            [E-1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836001
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Vanessa
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836002
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Kesya
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836003
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Charissa
                        )
                )

            [E-2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836004
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Drex
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836005
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Vulcano
                        )
                )
        )

    [08:30-09:30] => Array
        (
            [E-1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836001
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Vanessa
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836002
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Kesya
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836003
                            [mentor_code] => TPA-1
                            [student_name] => Charissa
                        )
                )

            [E-2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836004
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Drex
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836005
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Vulcano
                        )
                )
        )

    [10:00-11:00] => Array
        (
            [E-1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836001
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Vanessa
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836002
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Kesya
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836003
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Charissa
                        )
                )
        )

    [11:00-12:00] => Array
        (
            [E-1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836001
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Vanessa
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 1012836002
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Kesya
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [student_id] => 3012836003
                            [mentor_code] => FIS-1
                            [student_name] => Charissa
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

From the array, I am going to create tables like so:

```html
Time : 07:30-08:30    TPA-1    Class : E-1
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836001  | Vanessa      | Check None |
|1012836002  | Kesya        | Check None |
|3012836003  | Charissa     | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|

Time : 08:30-09:30    TPA-1    Class : E-1
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836001  | Vanessa      | Check None |
|1012836002  | Kesya        | Check None |
|3012836003  | Charissa     | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|

Time : 07:30-08:30     FIS-1   Class : E-2
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836004  | Drex         | Check None |
|3012836005  | Vulcano      | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|

Time : 08:30-09:30     FIS-1   Class : E-2
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836004  | Drex         | Check None |
|3012836005  | Vulcano      | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|

Time : 10:00-11:00    FIS-1    Class : E-1
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836001  | Vanessa      | Check None |
|1012836002  | Kesya        | Check None |
|3012836003  | Charissa     | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|

Time : 11:00-12:00    FIS-1    Class : E-1
|------------|--------------|------------|
|Student ID  | Student Name | Status     |
|------------|--------------|------------|
|1012836001  | Vanessa      | Check None |
|1012836002  | Kesya        | Check None |
|3012836003  | Charissa     | Check None |
|------------|--------------|------------|
```

Can I produce the results based on my array? I really need help. If someone here can point me to the right direction, would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by making your array *less multidimensional*.

Group your schedule rows by the full title:

```
foreach ($schedule as $row)
{
    $title = "Time : $row->time   $row->mentor_code   Class : $row->class_name";
    $tables[$title][] = $row;
}
```

Then you'll have an array of tables indexed by title. From that point it's much simpler to output each table.

```
foreach ($tables as $title => $table) {
    echo $title;
    echo '<table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Status</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';
    foreach ($table as $row) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$row->student_id}</td>
                <td>{$row->student_name}</td>
                <td>Check None</td>
              </tr>"
    }
    echo '</tbody>
          </table>';
}
```

Comment: Your codes work great! Thank you. It is really simple foreach loop and arrays :)